# How do I stop having carriage returns added to my file output in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to parse a BMP file, do some changes and then reassemble a new BMP using Python.

The carriage return seems to be a huge problem.  When I open the bitmap file using Notepad++ and search for `"\r'`, the character does not exist.  I read the file in Python (readData = fileIn.read()) and try searching using `readData.find('\r')` it returns `-1`.  Searching for `"\n"` works fine.  All is good for now.

When I try to write this exact same block of text into a new BMP using `fileOut.write(readData)` and I use Notepad++ to search for `"\r"`, I am able to find it (twice, each corresponding to the preexisting `"\n"` characters).

Is there a way to write this block of data to a new BMP without `"\r"` being added automatically?  I've tried applying `.strip()` and `.replace('\r','')` to the string before writing it to the new file.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably opening the file as text (the default) when you want to open it as binary.

```
open("example.bmp", "rb") # to [r]ead as [b]inary
open("example.bmp", "wb") # to [w]rite as [b]inary
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

Comment: bingo. Python converts the \n character because they assume you want a text file to be readable on the platform you are on. The binary flag tells Python "I don't want to open this in notepad or cat it out to a terminal, I want just the way it is, minus any edits I explicitly have you perform."

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file in text mode, while you need binary mode. Find more about open() here:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html